# JSON read as a string and cannot use data as a list

Tags: python, json, string, list

There are many questions related to json files here but somehow I'm not finding the answer to my issue.

I've dumped that data into a json_books.json file:

```
[{"title": "Pavot et mémoire", "author": ["Paul Celan"], "tags": ["Poésie"], "publisher": "Christian Bourgois", "pubdate": 1992}, {"title": "De seuil en seuil", "author": ["Paul Celan"], "tags": ["Poésie"], "publisher": "Christian Bourgois", "pubdate": 1991},  
{"title": "The 4 Disciplines of Execution: Achieving Your Wildly Important Goals", "author": ["Chris McChesney, Sean Covey, Jim Huling"], "tags": ["Business & Economics", "Management", "Self-Help", "Personal Growth", "Success", "Leadership"], "publisher": "Simon and Schuster", "pubdate": 2012},  
{"title": "Apprendre à finir", "author": ["Laurent Mauvignier"], "tags": ["Roman"], "publisher": "Les Editions de Minuit", "pubdate": 2004},  
//...]
```

**EDIT:**
To dump it, I used:

```
json_books = json.dumps(books, ensure_ascii=False)

with open('json_books.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(json_books, outfile, ensure_ascii=False)
```

--end edit--

So this is stored as a string. When I decode it with

```
with open('json_books.json') as file:
    books = json.loads(file.read())
```

Books is still only a string. But I'd like it to be a list.
If I try to decode without the `read()` function I get this error :

```
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper
```

And if I try to decode it with `load(file)` it is still just a string. So I cannot do anything with it.

Would someone know how I convert this back into a list ?

Comment: Have you run `type(books)` on the result? I get `<class 'list'>` so looks like it is decoding fine with your code.

Comment: @ChrisOram Yep, I have a <class 'str'> : the list is dumped and decoded as a string. Maybe I'll edit the dump part and add brackets so the question is clearer !

Comment: How did you dump to file?

Comment: Thanks @AnhPC03, I have edited the question to show how I did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you decode json file as string by

```
with open('json_books.json') as file:
    books = json.loads(file.read())
```

Then convert it to list by

```
books = json.loads(books)
```

Comment: I had solved it by not using dumps and only using dump — but your answer works too !  I never thought using `loads` again would create a list, I'll keep that in mind and accept your answer as the one, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ok it took me an hour to see it but my issue was easy.

Instead of

```
json_books = json.dumps(books, ensure_ascii=False)

with open('json_books.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(json_books, outfile, ensure_ascii=False)
```

I just did

```
with open('json_books.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(books, outfile, ensure_ascii=False)
```

And it works.

Indeed the first dumps is converting my data into string, so it is read back as a string.